# convert 2 Dimensional array String to 2 Dimensional Array Double

Tags: java, arrays, typeconverter, valueconverter

I have an array that contains number value and a String. I want convert that array into double. I have tried this:

```
int tableStringLength=tableString.length;
double [][]tableDouble= null;

for(int i=0; i<tableStringLength; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<tableStringLength; j++) {
        tableDouble[i][j]= Double.parseDouble(tableString[i][j]);
    }
}
```

but it returns nothing, not null or zero when I try to display in screen.

Comment: I understand that tableString is an array of String that are actually numbers , is it ?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't instantiate the double array:

```
double[][] tableDouble = new double[tableStringLength][tableStringLength];
```

Comment: Does tableString have any values? Are you able to print tableString values?

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all answer pals, but after i ask to my friend, she suggested to use

```
tableDouble[i][j]= Double.valueOf(tableString[i][j]).doubleValue();
```

and it works :)